# How many Magic Cubes?

Tags: code-golf

### Your Task:

You all know what a magic square is!  But what about a magic cube?  A magic cube is the 3D version of a magic square, and is a set of numbers in a cube, where the sums of every straight (not diagonal) line are equal.  You must write a program or function that receives an integer, and returns the number of valid magic cubes made up of up to one of each integer between 1 and that integer (inclusive).

### Input:

An integer.

### Output:

The number of magic cubes you can make by using up to one of of each integer between 1 and the input.  A cube with various rotations should only be counted once.

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte count wins.

### BOUNTY:

I will award a 100 rep bounty to the first user that manages to do this in < 100 bytes without using built-ins designed specifically towards magic cubes or squares (looking at you Mathematica).

Comment: So if a bunch of users all get <100 bytes you'll give +100 to all of them?

Comment: "Between integer 1 and the input." Inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Also, you might want to specify how exactly a magic cube works.

Comment: A magic cube "is a set of numbers in a cube, where the sums of every straight (not diagonal) line are equal."

Comment: Test cases would be good.

Comment: Sorry @HyperNeutrino, fixed now.

Comment: Yes, I will add some as soon as I finish writing my (very ungolfed) code that is technically an answer.  Until then, I don't want to calculate one for any number > 27 (1-27 are all the number inputted)

Comment: It would quite literally take days to be reasonably sure you haven't missed one.  It took me nearly an hour to find the one I provided as an example.

Comment: for n=27 there are at least 4.I say at least because rows, columns, pillars, AND space diagonals sum to  42 but NOT cross section diagonals.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemiperfectMagicCube.html

Comment: The given magic cube is definitely not valid, since `9+31+60=100≠106=34+43+29`.

Comment: You should add some test cases

Comment: Thanks @Pietu1998.  Great, it took me quite a while just to find one I *thought* worked!

Comment: Thanks, @Jenny_mathy.  Sweet, despite the magic cube I though I found being wrong, turns out that there are magic cubes.

Comment: I will @LuisMendo, as soon as I manage to make sure I have a test case that I haven't missed any magic cubes for.

Comment: “A cube with various rotations should only be counted once.” What about reflections? Or permutation of layers?

Comment: Reflections and permutations are counted multiple times, as they are technically different cubes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Clingo, 220 + 2 = 222 bytes

```
1{s(S):S=0..n,S**3==n}.
A{a(0..n-1,A)}:-A=1..n.
:-a(P,A-1),{a(P,A)}0,A<n.
:-s(S),{a(P,A):P-P/K\S*K=Q-Q/K\S*K}>(S*n+S)/2,Q=0..n,K=(1;S;S*S).
:-s(S),a(((0;1)+(0;S)+(0;S*S))*~-S,A),{a(0,A)}0.
:-s(S),a((S;S*S)*~-S,A),{a(S-1,A)}0.
```

Run with `clingo magic-cubes.lp -n0 -cn=INPUT`.  The answer will be printed next to `Models`.

All newlines are optional and shown here for clarity but excluded from the byte count.  I’m scoring +2 bytes for `-n0` (“count all models”).

The last two lines ensure that only one rotated version of each cube is counted.

The answers for 1, 8, 27 are quickly found to be 1, 0, 216; the rest are probably too hard.

If you want to see the cubes in a more readable format, add `b((P\S,P/S\S,P/S/S),A):s(S),-a(P,A),not a(P,A-1). #show b/2.`

```
$ clingo magic-cubes.lp -n0 -cn=1
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from magic-cubes.lp
Solving...
Answer: 1
a(0,1) s(1)
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 1
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.009s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.010s
$ clingo magic-cubes.lp -n0 -cn=8
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from magic-cubes.lp
Solving...
UNSATISFIABLE

Models       : 0
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.010s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
$ clingo magic-cubes.lp -n0 -cn=27
clingo version 5.1.0
Reading from magic-cubes.lp
Solving...
Answer: 1
a(7,1) a(7,2) a(13,2) a(7,3) a(13,3) a(19,3) a(7,4) a(13,4) a(15,4) a(19,4) a(7,5) a(13,5) a(15,5) a(19,5) a(21,5) a(0,6) a(7,6) a(13,6) a(15,6) a(19,6) a(21,6) a(0,7) a(7,7) a(13,7) a(15,7) a(19,7) a(21,7) a(26,7) a(0,8) a(5,8) a(7,8) a(13,8) a(15,8) a(19,8) a(21,8) a(26,8) a(0,9) a(5,9) a(7,9) a(11,9) a(13,9) a(15,9) a(19,9) a(21,9) a(26,9) a(0,10) a(2,10) a(5,10) a(7,10) a(11,10) a(13,10) a(15,10) a(19,10) a(21,10) a(26,10) a(0,11) a(2,11) a(5,11) a(7,11) a(11,11) a(13,11) a(15,11) a(17,11) a(19,11) a(21,11) a(26,11) a(0,12) a(2,12) a(5,12) a(7,12) a(11,12) a(13,12) a(15,12) a(17,12) a(19,12) a(21,12) a(23,12) a(26,12) a(0,13) a(2,13) a(5,13) a(7,13) a(10,13) a(11,13) a(13,13) a(15,13) a(17,13) a(19,13) a(21,13) a(23,13) a(26,13) a(0,14) a(2,14) a(5,14) a(7,14) a(10,14) a(11,14) a(13,14) a(15,14) a(17,14) a(19,14) a(21,14) a(23,14) a(25,14) a(26,14) a(0,15) a(2,15) a(4,15) a(5,15) a(7,15) a(10,15) a(11,15) a(13,15) a(15,15) a(17,15) a(19,15) a(21,15) a(23,15) a(25,15) a(26,15) a(0,16) a(2,16) a(4,16) a(5,16) a(7,16) a(10,16) a(11,16) a(13,16) a(15,16) a(17,16) a(18,16) a(19,16) a(21,16) a(23,16) a(25,16) a(26,16) a(0,17) a(2,17) a(4,17) a(5,17) a(6,17) a(7,17) a(10,17) a(11,17) a(13,17) a(15,17) a(17,17) a(18,17) a(19,17) a(21,17) a(23,17) a(25,17) a(26,17) a(0,18) a(2,18) a(4,18) a(5,18) a(6,18) a(7,18) a(10,18) a(11,18) a(12,18) a(13,18) a(15,18) a(17,18) a(18,18) a(19,18) a(21,18) a(23,18) a(25,18) a(26,18) a(0,19) a(2,19) a(3,19) a(4,19) a(5,19) a(6,19) a(7,19) a(10,19) a(11,19) a(12,19) a(13,19) a(15,19) a(17,19) a(18,19) a(19,19) a(21,19) a(23,19) a(25,19) a(26,19) a(0,20) a(2,20) a(3,20) a(4,20) a(5,20) a(6,20) a(7,20) a(9,20) a(10,20) a(11,20) a(12,20) a(13,20) a(15,20) a(17,20) a(18,20) a(19,20) a(21,20) a(23,20) a(25,20) a(26,20) a(0,21) a(2,21) a(3,21) a(4,21) a(5,21) a(6,21) a(7,21) a(9,21) a(10,21) a(11,21) a(12,21) a(13,21) a(15,21) a(17,21) a(18,21) a(19,21) a(21,21) a(23,21) a(24,21) a(25,21) a(26,21) a(0,22) a(2,22) a(3,22) a(4,22) a(5,22) a(6,22) a(7,22) a(9,22) a(10,22) a(11,22) a(12,22) a(13,22) a(14,22) a(15,22) a(17,22) a(18,22) a(19,22) a(21,22) a(23,22) a(24,22) a(25,22) a(26,22) a(0,23) a(2,23) a(3,23) a(4,23) a(5,23) a(6,23) a(7,23) a(9,23) a(10,23) a(11,23) a(12,23) a(13,23) a(14,23) a(15,23) a(17,23) a(18,23) a(19,23) a(20,23) a(21,23) a(23,23) a(24,23) a(25,23) a(26,23) a(0,24) a(2,24) a(3,24) a(4,24) a(5,24) a(6,24) a(7,24) a(8,24) a(9,24) a(10,24) a(11,24) a(12,24) a(13,24) a(14,24) a(15,24) a(17,24) a(18,24) a(19,24) a(20,24) a(21,24) a(23,24) a(24,24) a(25,24) a(26,24) a(0,25) a(2,25) a(3,25) a(4,25) a(5,25) a(6,25) a(7,25) a(8,25) a(9,25) a(10,25) a(11,25) a(12,25) a(13,25) a(14,25) a(15,25) a(17,25) a(18,25) a(19,25) a(20,25) a(21,25) a(22,25) a(23,25) a(24,25) a(25,25) a(26,25) a(0,26) a(1,26) a(2,26) a(3,26) a(4,26) a(5,26) a(6,26) a(7,26) a(8,26) a(9,26) a(10,26) a(11,26) a(12,26) a(13,26) a(14,26) a(15,26) a(17,26) a(18,26) a(19,26) a(20,26) a(21,26) a(22,26) a(23,26) a(24,26) a(25,26) a(26,26) a(0,27) a(1,27) a(2,27) s(3) a(3,27) a(4,27) a(5,27) a(6,27) a(7,27) a(8,27) a(9,27) a(10,27) a(11,27) a(12,27) a(13,27) a(14,27) a(15,27) a(16,27) a(17,27) a(18,27) a(19,27) a(20,27) a(21,27) a(22,27) a(23,27) a(24,27) a(25,27) a(26,27)
Answer: 2
[…]
Answer: 216
a(0,2) a(12,1) a(12,2) a(0,3) a(12,3) a(24,3) a(0,4) a(12,4) a(22,4) a(24,4) a(0,5) a(10,5) a(12,5) a(22,5) a(24,5) a(0,6) a(7,6) a(10,6) a(12,6) a(22,6) a(24,6) a(0,7) a(5,7) a(7,7) a(10,7) a(12,7) a(22,7) a(24,7) a(0,8) a(5,8) a(7,8) a(10,8) a(12,8) a(20,8) a(22,8) a(24,8) a(0,9) a(5,9) a(7,9) a(10,9) a(12,9) a(17,9) a(20,9) a(22,9) a(24,9) a(0,10) a(5,10) a(7,10) a(10,10) a(12,10) a(16,10) a(17,10) a(20,10) a(22,10) a(24,10) a(0,11) a(4,11) a(5,11) a(7,11) a(10,11) a(12,11) a(16,11) a(17,11) a(20,11) a(22,11) a(24,11) a(0,12) a(4,12) a(5,12) a(7,12) a(10,12) a(12,12) a(16,12) a(17,12) a(19,12) a(20,12) a(22,12) a(24,12) a(0,13) a(4,13) a(5,13) a(7,13) a(10,13) a(12,13) a(16,13) a(17,13) a(19,13) a(20,13) a(22,13) a(24,13) a(26,13) a(0,14) a(4,14) a(5,14) a(7,14) a(10,14) a(12,14) a(14,14) a(16,14) a(17,14) a(19,14) a(20,14) a(22,14) a(24,14) a(26,14) a(0,15) a(2,15) a(4,15) a(5,15) a(7,15) a(10,15) a(12,15) a(14,15) a(16,15) a(17,15) a(19,15) a(20,15) a(22,15) a(24,15) a(26,15) a(0,16) a(2,16) a(4,16) a(5,16) a(6,16) a(7,16) a(10,16) a(12,16) a(14,16) a(16,16) a(17,16) a(19,16) a(20,16) a(22,16) a(24,16) a(26,16) a(0,17) a(2,17) a(4,17) a(5,17) a(6,17) a(7,17) a(10,17) a(12,17) a(14,17) a(16,17) a(17,17) a(19,17) a(20,17) a(21,17) a(22,17) a(24,17) a(26,17) a(0,18) a(2,18) a(4,18) a(5,18) a(6,18) a(7,18) a(9,18) a(10,18) a(12,18) a(14,18) a(16,18) a(17,18) a(19,18) a(20,18) a(21,18) a(22,18) a(24,18) a(26,18) a(0,19) a(2,19) a(4,19) a(5,19) a(6,19) a(7,19) a(9,19) a(10,19) a(11,19) a(12,19) a(14,19) a(16,19) a(17,19) a(19,19) a(20,19) a(21,19) a(22,19) a(24,19) a(26,19) a(0,20) a(2,20) a(4,20) a(5,20) a(6,20) a(7,20) a(8,20) a(9,20) a(10,20) a(11,20) a(12,20) a(14,20) a(16,20) a(17,20) a(19,20) a(20,20) a(21,20) a(22,20) a(24,20) a(26,20) a(0,21) a(2,21) a(4,21) a(5,21) a(6,21) a(7,21) a(8,21) a(9,21) a(10,21) a(11,21) a(12,21) a(14,21) a(16,21) a(17,21) a(19,21) a(20,21) a(21,21) a(22,21) a(23,21) a(24,21) a(26,21) a(0,22) a(2,22) a(4,22) a(5,22) a(6,22) a(7,22) a(8,22) a(9,22) a(10,22) a(11,22) a(12,22) a(14,22) a(16,22) a(17,22) a(18,22) a(19,22) a(20,22) a(21,22) a(22,22) a(23,22) a(24,22) a(26,22) a(0,23) a(2,23) a(4,23) a(5,23) a(6,23) a(7,23) a(8,23) a(9,23) a(10,23) a(11,23) a(12,23) a(14,23) a(15,23) a(16,23) a(17,23) a(18,23) a(19,23) a(20,23) a(21,23) a(22,23) a(23,23) a(24,23) a(26,23) a(0,24) a(2,24) a(3,24) a(4,24) a(5,24) a(6,24) a(7,24) a(8,24) a(9,24) a(10,24) a(11,24) a(12,24) a(14,24) a(15,24) a(16,24) a(17,24) a(18,24) a(19,24) a(20,24) a(21,24) a(22,24) a(23,24) a(24,24) a(26,24) a(0,25) a(1,25) a(2,25) a(3,25) a(4,25) a(5,25) a(6,25) a(7,25) a(8,25) a(9,25) a(10,25) a(11,25) a(12,25) a(14,25) a(15,25) a(16,25) a(17,25) a(18,25) a(19,25) a(20,25) a(21,25) a(22,25) a(23,25) a(24,25) a(26,25) a(0,26) a(1,26) a(2,26) a(3,26) a(4,26) a(5,26) a(6,26) a(7,26) a(8,26) a(9,26) a(10,26) a(11,26) a(12,26) a(14,26) a(15,26) a(16,26) a(17,26) a(18,26) a(19,26) a(20,26) a(21,26) a(22,26) a(23,26) a(24,26) a(25,26) a(26,26) a(0,27) a(1,27) a(2,27) s(3) a(3,27) a(4,27) a(5,27) a(6,27) a(7,27) a(8,27) a(9,27) a(10,27) a(11,27) a(12,27) a(13,27) a(14,27) a(15,27) a(16,27) a(17,27) a(18,27) a(19,27) a(20,27) a(21,27) a(22,27) a(23,27) a(24,27) a(25,27) a(26,27)
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 216
Calls        : 1
Time         : 6.101s (Solving: 6.07s 1st Model: 1.03s Unsat: 0.37s)
CPU Time     : 6.090s
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is asking for

Comment: This appears to calculate the number of valid magic cubes with side length `n`, whereas the question is asking for the number for valid magic cubes in which every number is unique and less than or equal to `n`.

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect.

Comment: @ASCII-only Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 275 bytes

```ruby
n=gets.to_i;p (2.upto(n**(1/3r)).map{|i|(1..n).to_a.permutation(i**3).map{|x|c=eval'x'+".each_slice(#{i}).to_a"*2;[c,c.map(&:transpose),c.transpose.map(&:transpose)].map{|q|q.map{|a|a.map{|b|b.inject(:+)}}.flatten.uniq.length}.inject(:+)==3?1:0}}+[0]).flatten.inject(:+)/48+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcxha8JADAbgvzIczLvriLbdh1Ep@yEikh5RT2p6bdPh8O63d5MOFfz2JnnedEP1M45c7kl6kGbrVv5FZTB4aRQbo9JF3mkNJ/SX4IJKAVhfHYKn7jQIimtYOWPyf3QOtqRvrOfneTIDQnvY9rWzpF4vLk7VmclWa/turwX1VkiH3PumJ/23ug1Px830vw3tFDDgFKpQgeMjWVFFomOEXY0ixDCwa6Em3sshPoiyzL/SYhljsl5u9E3fweLjM@FxzH4B)

In theory, this works. In practice, since it creates every permutation of the list of possible numbers, it'll take hopelessly large amounts of time and memory for any input more than 13 or so. I haven't taken the time to test it past 12, but it seems no 2×2×2 magic cubes exist for that range, so all it really does is tell you how many 1×1×1 cubes you can make.

I "golfed" it a bit (really just made it hard to read for minimal size reduction returns). I'm sure the size can be reduced quite a bit, though getting it under 100 characters is a pretty tall order.

Ruby 2.4 added `.sum`, but TIO doesn't support it yet, so this has a few `.inject(:+)`s.

I'll add a non-golfed version + explanation if requested.

Comment: There are no 2×2×2 magic cubes with any range. The top face would have to be a 2×2 magic square, but there aren't any of those either: a1+a2 = a1+b1, so a2=b1, which violates the rule that all the values must be distinct.

Comment: @ais523 You're right; I hadn't thought of that. In that case, I'm going to abandon this solution seeing as it's not a viable way of finding 3-cubes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 bytes

```
;Z;Z€ẎS€E
*3³œcŒ!€Ẏs€s€¹Ç€S
Ç€ḊS÷24+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/986yjrqUdOah7v6goGUK5eW8aHNRycnH52kCBEtBlIgfGjn4XYgFcwFph7u6Ao@vN3IRPv///8WAA)

As you expect, it's terribly slow.

### Explanation

- Link 1: Given a cube, check if it's valid.

```
;Z;Z€ẎS€E   Input: N =
            [  [ [a,b],    [ [e,f],
                 [c,d] ],    [g,h] ]   ]

;Z          Concatenate with zip of N. The zip (transpose) of N is
            [   [ [a,b],    [ [c,d],
                  [e,f] ],    [g,h] ]   ]
            (by treating each 2-element block as an unit
            and transpose the large table)

;Z€         Concatenate with plane-wise zip of N, that is
            [  [ [a,c],    [ [e,g],
                 [b,d] ],    [f,h] ]   ]
            (transpose each 2x2 block)

            The current value is:
            [ [ [a,b],   [ [e,f],   [ [a,b],   [ [c,d],   [ [a,c],   [ [e,g],
                 [c,d] ],   [g,h] ],   [e,f] ],   [g,h] ],   [b,d] ],   [f,h] ] ]

Ẏ           Tighten, concatenate all elements inside, similar to `;/`.
            Get [ [a,b], [c,d], [e,f], [g,h],
                  [a,b], [e,f], [c,d], [g,h],
                  [a,c], [b,d], [e,g], [f,h] ]
S€          Sum each sublist. `ZS` also works.
E           All Equal? `1` if all elements are equal, `0` otherwise.
```

- Link 2: Given a side length `x`, generate all cubes with that side length and calculate number of valid cubes.

```
*3³œcŒ!€Ẏs€s€¹Ç€S   Given: `x` (side length).
*3                  Calculate x³.
  ³                 First commandline argument. (n)
   œc               Generate all subsets of the range `[1..n]` having length x³.
     Œ!€Ẏ           All permutation of each and tighten.
                      (the current value is a list of all ways to choose
                      an ordered tuple of x³ elements from `[1..n]`)
         s€s€       Split each twice into slices of length `x`.
                      On a list of (list of x³ integers), this format
                      each sublist into a cube.
             ¹      Do nothing. Because Jelly is a tacit programming language
                      without this the program will behave differently.
              Ç€    Apply last link for €ach.
                S   Sum.
```

- Link 3 (main link): For all side lengths from `1` to `n`, calculate number of cubes (rotations are counted multiple times) for each side length, dequeue and sum it (so we get the sum of number of cubes with side length `>= 2`), divide by `24` (to avoid duplication of cubes) and add the number of side length 1 cube (input).

```
Ç          Apply last link...
 €           for €ach element from `1` to `n`.
  Ḋ        Ḋequeue, dispose the result for value 1.
   S÷24    Sum and divide by 24.
       +   Add the input (number of cubes with side length 1)
```